# Laravel:session is not keep alive when deploying to server

Tags: linux, laravel, authentication, session, session-state

every time I make an authentication with a user, the session stays alive as long as I do not leave the page, or close the tab, however, when I access the page again, the session is closed and I must authenticate again, this only happens when I deploy the server, since it works correctly locally, I have reviewed all related files, this is my session.php file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,
```

this is my .env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

all folders in my project on the server have 777 permissions,what could be happening?

Comment: all folders for the project shouldn't have 777 permissions. Maybe something like 755 and owned by the web worker?

Answer (score 0):

Using database session driver would solve your problem and improve code quality. Check out [this docs section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#driver-prerequisites) on how to configure it.